# Array of pointers to string

Tags: c, string, pointers, multidimensional-array

When we are using a 2-D array of characters we are at liberty to either initialize the strings where we are declaring the array,or receive the string using scanf() fucntion.However when we are using an array of pointers we can not receive the strings from keyboard using scanf(). why?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
char *names[6];
int i;
for(i=0;i<=5;i++)
{

    printf("Enter name:");
    scanf("%s",names[i]);

}
return 0;
```

Comment: Because the pointers don't point to anywhere you can write to?

Comment: Also this is *not* a 2D array of characters. Look up the basics about the difference between pointers and arrays in C.

Answer (score 4):

Your code doesn't work because it invokes undefined behavior by storing strings into pointers which are not initialized to point to anything.  You need to use `malloc()`.

`valgrind` is a tool which would catch this sort of program for you, automatically.

Answer (score 3):

```
 char *names[6];
```

declares `names` as an array of pointers to `char` but does not allocate memory for elements of `names`. You need to allocate memory for each element before writing to it, otherwise it will invoke *undefined behavior*.

Try this:

```
for(i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
     printf("Enter name:");
     names[i] = malloc(SIZE);  // SIZE is for length of string
     if( names[i] != NULL)
         scanf("%s", names[i]);
}
```

Comment: @Down Voter; A comment would be appreciated.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but perhaps it was due to your use of `gets`   (spelled slightly differently), or failure to check return value of `malloc`

Answer (score 2):

scanf does not allocate memory automatically, so you have to allocate a buffer for storing the input before calling scanf.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
char *names[6];
int i;
for(i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
printf("Enter name:");
names[i]=(char *)malloc(256); // 256 is size of buffer
scanf("%s",names[i]);

}
return 0;
```